# Content is not displayed in front page

Tags: theming

I am using drupal 7. In theming i have created page--front.tpl.php

Every thing is working properly, but when i create a basic page and assign it to display on front page then page is not rendered.

I have also written this `<?php print render($page['content']) ?>` but content is not being rendered. It is showing error

> No front page content has been created yet. Add new content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had installed [weight](http://drupal.org/project/weight) module to assign weight to nodes. This was creating problem. I just uninstalled it to debug and surprisingly it was working, but to work with weight module i assigned -1 weight to front page content and it started displaying the content.

Answer (score 1):

That's the message you get for the standard front page (located at `/node`), so it looks like your attempt to update which page is the front page hasn't taken for some reason.

In case you've done it another way, the usual way to set this front page is to go to `admin/config/system/site-information` and set the "Default Front Page" to the path of the new node that you've created.

You'll also need to clear Drupal's caches once you've added the new template file in case you haven't done that already.